# Grep "Exception" but filter out one specific case, based on previous line

Tags: regex, grep, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In my application, I have modified all IP addresses, in order not to disturb the actual production system. As a result, my application is throwing lots of exceptions. Those are kept in a logfile, called `filename`.

I would like to filter the exceptions, but I don't want to see the ones, caused by the modification of the IP addresses.

This sounds very easy, because those exceptions are preceded by a line, containing `Failed to connect`.

Let's see how to do this:

Filter on exceptions:

```
grep "Exception" filename
```

Show also the previous line:

```
grep -B 1 "Exception" filename
```

Do not show the lines, containing "Failed to connect":

```
grep -B 1 "Exception filename | grep -v "Failed to connect"
```

=> No, this is not what I want: this filters out the lines, containing the words "Failed to connect", but the actual exceptions are still shown. How can I not only filter out the exceptions too?

My `filename` contents are something like:

```
... Failed to connect ...
... Exception ...
...
... (lots of these)
...
... <something else than "Failed to connect">
... Exception ...
...
... Failed to connect ...
... Exception ...
...
... (again lots of these)
...
```

I'm only interested in the lines `... Exception ...` who are not preceded by "Failed to connect".

When I press `man grep`, it ends with:

```
GNU grep 3.4 ... 2019-12-29
```

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you consider `sed` or `awk` also?

Comment: @anubhava: I would consider `awk` indeed, but I was hoping for a pure `grep` solution. Am I hoping for too much? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu-grep` you may be able to do this:

```bash
grep -zoP '(?m)^(?!.*Failed to connect).+\R.*Exception.*\R' file

... foo bar baz
... Exception ...

# where file content is
cat file

.. Failed to connect ...
... Exception ...
...
... (lots of these)
...
... foo bar baz
... Exception ...
...
... Failed to connect ...
... Exception ...
...
... (again lots of these)
...
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxcvnB/1)

**Command Details:**

- `-z`: Operate on full file instead of one line at a time
- `-o`: Return only matched text
- `-P`: Enable PCRE mode
- `(?m)`: Enable MULTILINE mode
- `^`: Match a line start
- `(?!.*Failed to connect)`: Negative lookahead to assert failure when we have `Failed to connect` anywhere on a line
- `.+\R`: Match 1+ of any characters followed by a line break
- `.*Exception.*\R`: Match 0+ of any characters then text `Exception` then again 0 or more of any characters followed by a line break

Comment: Such a great answer and I can only give one upvote. I hate this site :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following GNU `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk` with setting RS to `[^\n]*\\n[^E]*Exception[^\n]*` and then using `match` function to only get the required part as per shown output in `RT` variable of GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk -v RS='[^\n]*\\n[^E]*Exception[^\n]*' '
RT{
  if(RT!~/Failed to connect/ && RT~/Exception/){
    match(RT,/(^|\n)([^\n]*\n[^\n]*$)/,arr)
    sub(/^\n/,"",arr[1])
    print arr[1],arr[2]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***OR*** we could make above more efficient as following:

```
awk -v RS='[^\n]*\\n[^E]*Exception[^\n]*' '
RT{
  if(RT!~/Failed to connect/ && RT~/Exception/){
    match(RT,/(^|\n)([^\n]*\n[^\n]*$)/,arr)
    print arr[2]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: I'm convinced this might work, but I'll stay working with Anubhava's proposal.

Comment: @Dominique, sure, happy that I could try to help here, his answer is perfect; I just thought to contribute in this one, cheers and happy learning,